# How to pass D3DDevice in LibVLC to be the "HWND"

Tags: c++, video, directx, directshow, libvlc

I wanted to use libVCL to display a video in my game, however I have issues with using HWND when the game is in fullscreen, the fullscreen surface overlaps the video.

I do have the D3DDevice handle available though so the video could draw inside the game surface. 
But all I've found is libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd() and not a way to pass the video surface to my game's surface for drawing. Is there any way/example to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in LibVLC.

I think you need to use the video format callbacks and render the video buffer to a texture yourself. That is the I the approach I used (from Java with JMonkeyEngine for example).

See libvlc_video_set_callbacks, libvlc_video_set_format and libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks.

I've seen this play back full HD smoothly, but this will consume more CPU than having VLC render directly into a video surface.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, is there some code or thorough example I can follow for this? I don't mind the extra CPU work for that matter.

Comment: I only have Java code for this, not C++. I'm not sure how well it would translate, but it could give you some ideas: https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/vlcj-3.0.0/src/main/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/direct/DefaultDirectMediaPlayer.java